# Generic method may throw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a global linq extension method who retrieve the most represented element from a given list. Here is the sample :

```
public static T GetMostRepresentedElement<T, U>(this IEnumerable<U> _Collection, Func<U, T> _GetElem)
{
    return _Collection.GroupBy(e => _GetElem(e))
                      .Select(f => new
                      {
                          Count = f.Count(),
                          Elem = f.Key
                      })
                      .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
                      .First()
                      .Elem;
}
```

It happends that this block of code throw an exception :

> At First: Sequence contains no elements StackTrace:    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)    at
>   IHMTools.Utilities.LinqExtensions.GetMostRepresentedElement[T,U](IEnumerable1
>   _Collection, Func2 _GetElem)

How is it possible for me to make this method safe ?
Do I have to make a fix on this method, or is it better to be carefull about what data I sent to the method ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the collection is empty, `First()` will throw the exception you received.  You can use `FirstOrDefault()` to return the default for `T` for the empty case instead.

As your LINQ is quite involved you might be best with an early exit to handle the case, then you also avoid the null case as commenters have pointed out.  Something like `if (!_Collection.Any()) return default(T);`

Comment: Note that getting `Elem` of a null object will give you a follow up problem.

Comment: Just noticed the generic type is unbounded, so could be a `struct`, so it might not be null.

Comment: @batwad Indeed. See my answer how to fix that another way.

Comment: Just to complete, I fixed it to make sure before calling the method that there is entry in my collection. Thanks for eveythink and have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that there are no items returned from your first part of the expression. Getting the first item of an empty collection will thrown an exception.

You could use `FirstOrDefault()` and then makes sure you won't get follow up null reference exceptions:

```
public static T GetMostRepresentedElementStruct<T, U>(this IEnumerable<U> _Collection, Func<U, T> _GetElem)
{
    var t = _Collection.GroupBy(e => _GetElem(e))
                       .Select(f => new
                       {
                           Count = f.Count(),
                           Elem = f.Key
                       })
                       .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
                       .FirstOrDefault();

    if (t == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    else
    {
        return t.Elem;
    }
}
```